# apparmor - can't print, found 32 profiles are in enforce mode

Tags: printing, 20.10, apparmor

I recently installed Ubuntu 20.10 (had been using 18.04).  I tried printing (which I had no problem doing before) and noticed apparmor messages about cups being DENIED.  I found some sites which had me install apparmor-utils and set complain mode for anything cups related, but I still can't print, and get similar messages, when trying to do so but now labeled ALLOWED:

```
[  735.428563] audit: type=1400 audit(1606403130.615:72): apparmor="ALLOWED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/cupsd" name="/proc/3390/attr/apparmor/current" pid=792 comm="cupsd" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=0 ouid=114
```

In addition, it seems crazy to me that there would be 29 other programs in enforce mode.  Is this normal?

```
apparmor module is loaded.
35 profiles are loaded.
29 profiles are in enforce mode.
   /snap/snapd/9721/usr/lib/snapd/snap-confine
   /snap/snapd/9721/usr/lib/snapd/snap-confine//mount-namespace-capture-helper
   /usr/bin/evince
   /usr/bin/evince-previewer
   /usr/bin/evince-previewer//sanitized_helper
   /usr/bin/evince-thumbnailer
   /usr/bin/evince//sanitized_helper
   /usr/bin/man
   /usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dhcp-client.action
   /usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dhcp-helper
   /usr/lib/connman/scripts/dhclient-script
   /usr/lib/snapd/snap-confine
   /usr/lib/snapd/snap-confine//mount-namespace-capture-helper
   /usr/sbin/cupsd//third_party
   /{,usr/}sbin/dhclient
   libreoffice-senddoc
   libreoffice-soffice//gpg
   libreoffice-xpdfimport
   lsb_release
   man_filter
   man_groff
   nvidia_modprobe
   nvidia_modprobe//kmod
   snap-update-ns.snap-store
   snap.snap-store.hook.configure
   snap.snap-store.snap-store
   snap.snap-store.ubuntu-software
   snap.snap-store.ubuntu-software-local-file
   tcpdump
6 profiles are in complain mode.
   /usr/lib/cups/backend/cups-pdf
   /usr/sbin/cups-browsed
   /usr/sbin/cupsd
   /usr/sbin/sssd
   libreoffice-oopslash
   libreoffice-soffice
0 profiles are in kill mode.
0 profiles are in unconfined mode.
7 processes have profiles defined.
1 processes are in enforce mode.
   /snap/snap-store/498/usr/bin/snap-store (1670) snap.snap-store.ubuntu-software
6 processes are in complain mode.
   /usr/sbin/cups-browsed (847) 
   /usr/sbin/cupsd (792) 
   /usr/lib/cups/notifier/dbus (3432) /usr/sbin/cupsd
   /usr/lib/cups/notifier/dbus (3433) /usr/sbin/cupsd
   /usr/lib/libreoffice/program/oosplash (3324) libreoffice-oopslash
   /usr/lib/libreoffice/program/soffice.bin (3341) libreoffice-soffice
0 processes are unconfined but have a profile defined.
0 processes are in mixed mode.
0 processes are in kill mode.
```

Any help would be appreciated